# Laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-5.4

When I login for the first time it works perfectly but when I log out from my app and try to re-login I get this error.

I've tried almost every available solutions but can't solve the issue. Any solution to fix this error?

This is how I perform login and logout(Please correct me if the code is wrong as I'm new in laravel).

I've tried laravel-caffeine and {{ csrf_token() }}.

I think this is some session related issue.

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    $data = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (\Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $email = $request->email;
         $users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->select('users.*', 'user_name')
            ->get();

        Session::put('set', $users);

        if ($users[0]->is_admin == '1') {
            return redirect()->intended('adminDashboard');
        }else{
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }else{
        return back()->withInput()->witherrors(['Email or password did not match!']);
    }
}

public function logout(){
    Session::flush();
    return view('login/login');
}
```

Comment: and how do you logout and login?

Comment: Listing your solutions that you've tried, and the results, will help anyone answering to not suggest the same actions.

Comment: try (your project base path)/public/logout and then (base path)/public . It should work

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You error may be coming from your session manipulation. When you do

```
Auth::attempt($data)
```

The user is already set in the session. You don't need to do your `Session::put()` thingy. To get the user, do

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

To logout, you do

```
Auth::logout(); //will clear the user from the session automatically
```

So to summarise, remove all the session manipulations you have in your code. Only play with Auth;

```
Session::flush(); //DELETE THIS LINE
```

Add Auth to the top of your controller with

```
use Auth; //easier to work like that.
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the form has not declared the input tag of the token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your button to disconnect in a form? If so, you need to put this: {{ csrf_field }} in your form of type POST.

Answer (score 0):

Go to config/session file and check if you have this line below:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null)
```

If yes, then visit your `.env` file and also set like this:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=null
```

Then refresh, should be fine.