# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

When sending a post request When you send a query post, an error occurs
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

```
     <form action = "contact" method = "POST">
         Name <input type = "text" name ="param">
         Текст <textarea name = "" id = "" cols = "30" rows = "10></textarea> 
          <input type="submit" value = "submit">
     </form>
```

Comment: Make sure you're adding the csrf token to your form. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: No, it does not work either

Comment: Without more code, not much we can help with.

Comment: <form action="contact" method="POST">

    Name
    <input type="text" name="param">
    Text
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="post">-->

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: Adding the code to your post makes it a lot easier to read, and I do not see the csrf token there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687461/laravel-5-4-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-68)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not send token for csrf, in laravel provided for this special method `{{csrf_field()}}` 
you can read about it in detail here [laravel csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

```
<form action = "contact" method = "POST">
     {{csrf_field()}}
     Name <input type = "text" name ="param">
     Текст <textarea name = "" id = "" cols = "30" rows = "10></textarea> 
      <input type="submit" value = "submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add inside of your form `{{ csrf_field() }}`

```
<form>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input >
  ...
</form>
```

This will insert the hidden field for csrf token for you