# Laravel 5.4 Login Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.4, everything was very smooth on my development server, but once i move to Server, I having a problem when login to portal, the message show, "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68", and I already included token on the login submit form, but still getting this error.

Can someone guide me what to do, it struggle for few hours. Appreciate that if you could guide me to solve this error.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687461/laravel-5-4-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-68

did u checked this?

Comment: yes, i checked. not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format

go to Kernel.php and then comment this line in "protected $middlewareGroups"
like this
http://prntscr.com/fj4j7f

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

This is not a correct way but still this will work for you.

Can you send your login form codes, may be there any error when you adding CsrfToken

Comment: thank for comment, but i need the token check for verification. by the way, i Found the error, but still solving it, it is because then submit token is different with the session token.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure you pushed the cache your application had on your local project. Try and clear your application cache from the server with

php artisan clear:cache

Hope that works

Comment: i have tried on this, unfortunately is not working for me, thanks for the help,

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: Hi Willie, yes i mange to solve it. it is because of my session domain, i forgotten to change my Session Cookies Domain URL on session.php file. You're welcome to ask me, if you have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be your file permissions,

The CSRF token works by flashing the value to your session, then comparing the value with what was submitted with your form on the next request. If your sessions are not being set then this will always fail. make sure your Sessions work.

Try giving more permissions to this path `/storage/framework/sessions/*`

Comment: I have open permission for those folder, i realise is because of the token not match, the submit token is not matching with session token.

Comment: yes, I did it, I manage to fix the error, because i forget to change my session domain, so the session token different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you added `$this->middleware('auth');` inside the constructor of your controller to get the authentication working. Add the following at the top as well, under your login/register forms, if you are using  `{!! Form::someElement !!}`

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Or if you are using input tags inside your forms, just add this just after the  tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this errors, due to i forgotten to change my Session Cookie Domain, so when generate token ,it return two different token value. 
Thanks for the comment. Appreciate your help.